# R - Read a file of functions into a list

Tags: r

I have a file `functions.R` that's basically:

```
fun1 <- function(a,b) {
  ...
}

fun2 <- function(c,d) {
  ...
}

...
```

I want to process this into a list where the keys are the function names and the elements are the functions. This is for display on a shiny app. So the end product is:

`my_fun_list$fun1` has the string 
"fun1 <- function(a,b) { ... }"

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: You want the strings as the elements of the list, not the function objects? Can I ask why?

Comment: You have to call source() but pass a new empty  environment to the function. All the functions will reside in the new environment. You can then call as.list() on the environment. Afterwards you can deparse the list items.

Comment: I have a shiny that allows users to navigate through some data, one of the items is the function that was applied to the data... it would be nice to display the function in Shiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
e <- new.env()
sys.source("path/to/file.R", envir=e)
```

Now you can access each element within the R file as

```
e$myfunc()
```

To get the text of the functions (thanks @Gregor):

```
eapply(e, capture.output)
```

will give you `character` vectors for each file, though it will be the stripped function, no comments.

Comment: Maybe an `eapply` with `capture.output` or `deparse` could get the function code as strings as OP wants?

Comment: Nice and thanks!!. How can I coerce a function in memory to a string?

Comment: `capture.output(my_function_name)` or `sapply(c('funcname1','funcname2'), capture.output, simplify=FALSE)` will give you a list of function text-content, similar to the environment version.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks r2evans and Gregor!